# websocket with rails controller error: undefined method `action' for MessageController:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, websocket

I keep getting this error when I try to load the index page:

```
NoMethodError in MessageController#new_message
undefined method `action' for MessageController:Class
```

The error goes away if I replace `BaseController` with `ApplicationController`, but that also breaks a lot of other things and the tutorial(http://websocket-rails.github.io/) for rails-websocket has it as `BaseController`.

```
class MessageController <  WebsocketRails::BaseController

  def initialize_session
    # perform application setup here
    controller_store[:message_count] = 0
  end

  def new_message
    new_message = {:message => 'this is a message'}
    send_message :new_message, new_message
  end

  def index

  end
end
```

Does anyone know what the problem is here?

--
edit
using rails version 4.0.2
if that matters at all

Comment: How are you accessing this?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I ended up using another controller for the WebsocketRails::BaseController to handle websocket events. I think it has something to do with the route to index, create, etc... I think WebsocketRails::BaseController can't handle route requests. And maybe the `create` there in the reference link you've provided is just to `create` but not actually a REST method. Otherwise, there might be incompatibility with rails 4.0.2, or maybe a bug. I hope someone could answer this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this has been [reported as an issue](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/issues/194) on the project's issue tracker in the past, but has been closed (with non-fix).

The comment explaining the situation:

> You don't want to mix ApplicationController methods with ones from WebsocketRails::BaseController. In fact, WebsocketRails::BaseController is designed after ApplicationController and implements some of the same methods, namely process_action.

The solution I used (and which they also suggest), is to use 2 controllers. One inheriting from *WebsocketRails::BaseController* and another from *ActionController::Base* (Rails). Put your logic in a separate class and use it from both.